# Date filter includes time before date filter applied

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm trying to output the current Day-Month-Time in a django template

```
<li> {%now |date:"d-F-Y" %} </li>
```

outputs

11p.m.31CDT:"11-August-2014

Id like to to read just

11-August-2014

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to apply the `date` filter to [`now`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#now), use `{% now "d-F-Y" %}`:

```
>>> from django.template import Context, Template
>>> t = Template('{% now "d-F-Y" %}')
>>> t.render(Context())
u'11-August-2014'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{% now "d-F-Y" %}
```

Read the Documentation:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#now